# How do I restrict the tap area of my button to the shape and the label inside?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two navigation buttons in a VStack and I need help restricting the tap area to the shapes only. Currently, I'm able to tap slightly outside the shape in white space, w/o my cursor touching the shape at all.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSecondView: Bool = false
    @State var showThirdView: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // PLAY BUTTON
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                NavigationStack {
                    Button() {
                        showSecondView.toggle()
                    }
                label: {
                    Text("Play")
                        .font(.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 25))
                        .bold()
                        .buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 40)
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                        .background(.pink)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(25)
                }
                .navigationDestination(
                    isPresented: $showSecondView) {
                        SecondView()
                    }
                    Spacer().frame(height: 25) //space between buttons
                    // HOW TO PLAY BUTTON
                    Button() {
                        showThirdView.toggle()
                    }
                label: {
                    Text("How To Play")
                        .font(.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 25))
                        .bold()
                        .buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                        .padding(.vertical, 10)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(.pink)
                        .cornerRadius(25)
                }
                .navigationDestination(
                    isPresented: $showThirdView) {
                        ThirdView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I need to add or remove to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the tap area to only the shape of the button using `.contentShape(Rectangle())`

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSecondView: Bool = false
    @State var showThirdView: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                NavigationStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        showSecondView.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Play")
                            .font(.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 25))
                            .bold()
                    }
                    .buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 40)
                    .padding(.vertical, 10)
                    .background(.pink)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(25)
                    .contentShape(Rectangle()) // Restrict tap area
                    .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showSecondView) {
                        SecondView()
                    }

                    Spacer().frame(height: 25)

                    Button(action: {
                        showThirdView.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("How To Play")
                            .font(.custom("Helvetica Neue", size: 25))
                            .bold()
                    }
                    .buttonBorderShape(.capsule)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                    .padding(.vertical, 10)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(.pink)
                    .cornerRadius(25)
                    .contentShape(Rectangle())
                    .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showThirdView) {
                        ThirdView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Preview
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```